# How can I properly extract the string element 'text' from my struct into my UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, struct, swift4

I have searched endlessly for a way to remove my single error in my code.  I am trying to populate a `UITableView` with Firebase data for my list of categories.  Then in my `cellForRowAt` section of my tableView below, there is a line that is a throwing an error; '`cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]`' saying

> Cannot assign value of type 'Category' to a type 'String?'.

I am trying to make the name of the category show up here, but it's not working.  Could my declarations be incorrect for '`var: [Category] = []`'?  or am I missing the extraction of JUST 'the 'text' element of my struct into my array?

I have the following struct for 'category':

```
import Foundation
import Firebase    

struct Category {

    let text: String
    let key: String
    let creationDate: Date

    init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
        text = snapshotValue["text"] as? String ?? ""
        key = snapshotValue["key"] as? String ?? ""

        let secondsFrom1970 = snapshotValue["creationDate"] as? Double ?? 0
        creationDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: secondsFrom1970)
    }

    func toAnyObject() -> Any {
        return [
            "text": text,
        ]
    }
}
```

I then use it to populate a UITableView using the following:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class CategoriesController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var sRefKey: String = ""
    var items = [Category]()
    let cellId = "cellId"

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = nil
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .mxGreen()
        tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = nil
        tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.title = "Categories"

        let tableView: UITableView = UITableView()
        let displayWidth: CGFloat = self.view.frame.width
        let displayHeight: CGFloat = self.view.frame.height

        tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: displayWidth, height: displayHeight)
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)

        tableView.backgroundColor = .white
        tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: -50, right: 0)
        tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: -50, right: 0)
        tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true
        self.categoryTextField.delegate = self

        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("categories")
        ref.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

            var newCategories = [Category]()

            for item in snapshot.children {
                let categoryItem = Category(snapshot: item as! DataSnapshot)
                newCategories.append(categoryItem)
            }
            self.items = newCategories
            self.items.sort(by: { (u1, u2) -> Bool in
                return u1.text.compare(u2.text) == .orderedAscending
            })
            tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("it won't open")
        handleEditCategory()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        return cell
    }

    func handleEditCategory() {
        print("Handling Edit a Category")
        let editCategoryController = EditCategoryController()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(editCategoryController, animated: true)
    }

    lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.backgroundColor = .white
        containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50)

        let submitButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        submitButton.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)
        submitButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        submitButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
        submitButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSubmit), for: .touchUpInside)
        containerView.addSubview(submitButton)
        submitButton.anchor(top: containerView.topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: containerView.bottomAnchor, right: containerView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 12, width: 50, height: 0)

        containerView.addSubview(self.categoryTextField)
        self.categoryTextField.anchor(top: containerView.topAnchor, left: containerView.leftAnchor, bottom: containerView.bottomAnchor, right: submitButton.leftAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 12, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

        let lineSeparatorView = UIView()
        lineSeparatorView.backgroundColor = .lineSeparatorColor()
        containerView.addSubview(lineSeparatorView)
        lineSeparatorView.anchor(top: containerView.topAnchor, left: containerView.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: containerView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0.5)

        return containerView
    }()

    let categoryTextField: UITextField = {
        let categoryTextField = UITextField()
        categoryTextField.placeholder = "Enter new category"
        return categoryTextField
    }()

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.categoryTextField.resignFirstResponder()  //if desired
        handleSubmit()
        self.categoryTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    @objc func handleSubmit() {
        let values = ["text": categoryTextField.text ?? "", "creationDate": Date().timeIntervalSince1970] as [String : Any]
        if categoryTextField.text?.count != 0 {
            let submitRef = Database.database().reference().child("categories")
            let sRef = submitRef.childByAutoId()
            self.sRefKey = sRef.key
            submitRef.child(self.sRefKey).updateChildValues(["key": self.sRefKey])
            submitRef.child(self.sRefKey).updateChildValues(values)
            print("Successfully added category.")
        } else {
            print("Category not added.")
        }
        self.categoryTextField.text = nil
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        get {
            return containerView
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        let dismissRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.default, title: "Delete", handler:{action, indexPath in

            let category = self.items[indexPath.row]
            let categoryId = category.key
            Database.database().reference().child("categories").child(categoryId).removeValue(completionBlock: { (err, ref) in

                if let err = err {
                    print("Failed to remove group: ", err)
                    return
                }
                print("Successfully removed group via groupId.")
            })

        })
        dismissRowAction.backgroundColor = .mxRed()

        return [dismissRowAction]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i see, you just need to change `cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]` to `cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row].text`.

It will work. Because `items[indexPath.row]` is a `Category` and you just need to use `text` of `Category`, not assign `Category` struct for `label.text` ;)

Comment: Thanks!  As you were the first with the solution, I gave you credit, but thanks to you and Leon Leung both!

Comment: Very fair. Thank you @Mattnet

Comment: mistyped above..Leon Leung should be Louis Leung.  Apologies!

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are passing your entire Category struct instead of a string property from the Category... Use the property of Category that stores the name you want displayed instead:

Looking at your struct initialiser, it will probably be:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row].key
```

or

```
cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row].text
```

Comment: Wow!  I posted quite a bit of info for 5 missing characters!  Thank you so much Louis Leung!